# sentence similarity using word embedding

Tags: python, scipy

I am a PhD researcher and started using word2vec for my research. I just want to use it for calculating sentence similarity. I searched and found few links but I couldn't run those. I was looking at the following:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import spatial

index2word_set = set(model.wv.index2word)

def avg_feature_vector(sentence, model, num_features, index2word_set):
    words = sentence.split()
    feature_vec = np.zeros((num_features, ), dtype='float32')
    n_words = 0
    for word in words:
        if word in index2word_set:
            n_words += 1
            feature_vec = np.add(feature_vec, model[word])
    if (n_words > 0):
        feature_vec = np.divide(feature_vec, n_words)
    return feature_vec

s1_afv = avg_feature_vector('this is a sentence', model=model,   num_features=300, index2word_set=index2word_set)
s2_afv = avg_feature_vector('this is also sentence', model=model,num_features=300, index2word_set=index2word_set)
sim = 1 - spatial.distance.cosine(s1_afv, s2_afv)
print(sim)
```

unfortunately I couldn't run this as I don't know how I can find "index2word_set". In addition, should I assign model= ? Or, are there any easy commands or instruction to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

assign model to the model that you generated or any predefined word2vec model that you want to use
and as for index2word_set, you can set it to model.wv

It should work then.